# Monitor CPU voltage and overclock

Tags: raspbian, overclocking, cpu

Is there a way to monitor the current CPU core voltage and overclock, similarly to CPU-Z but for the raspberry pi? This is so I can check that nothing is limiting the overvolt or overclock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These commands should do it.

```
vcgencmd measure_clock arm
vcgencmd measure_volts core
```

If you like to monitor them in realtime, you can use `watch`:

```
watch -n1 "vcgencmd measure_clock arm && vcgencmd measure_volts core
```

or you can add a cronjob to write it inside file.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Does this show what the overclock/overvolt is meant to be, or what it currently is?

Comment: It shows what there currently is. You can try that by workloading your CPU. For that you can use [stress](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/) . It's availible for Archlinux ARM even for Raspbian in official repositories.